# windows git clone from linux

Tags: git, cygwin, git-clone

I have installed Cygwin Terminal on my windows. And I try to clone the git repository we have on a linux server with command :

```
$ git clone ssh://some.server.com/somename
Cloning into 'somename'...
ituser3@some.server.com's password:
```

I know that there is SSL certificate in the server.

How can I get it connecting without password? How can it take into account the certificate on the server?

Comment: [ssh login without password](http://linuxproblem.org/art_9.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

copy and pasted from [mathias kettner's tutorial](http://linuxproblem.org/art_9.html)

First log in on A as user a and generate a pair of authentication keys. Do not enter a passphrase:

```
a@A:~> ssh-keygen -t rsa
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/a/.ssh/id_rsa): 
Created directory '/home/a/.ssh'.
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in /home/a/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /home/a/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
3e:4f:05:79:3a:9f:96:7c:3b:ad:e9:58:37:bc:37:e4 a@A
```

Now use ssh to create a directory ~/.ssh as user b on B. (The directory may already exist, which is fine):

```
a@A:~> ssh b@B mkdir -p .ssh
b@B's password:
```

Finally append a's new public key to b@B:.ssh/authorized_keys and enter b's password one last time:

```
a@A:~> cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh b@B 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys'
b@B's password:
```

From now on you can log into B as b from A as a without password:

```
a@A:~> ssh b@B hostname
B
```

Comment: I am trying this now. Do you think it should work on windows as well?

Comment: i've used those instructions from [git-bash](https://openhatch.org/missions/windows-setup/install-git-bash) the windows client. if you only need to use git on your windows machine and cygwin doesn't work i'd suggest trying that.